# Does java allow you to instantiate a class inside a jar that extends a class from a jar inside the first jar?

Tags: java, openapi

I'm being tasked in my internship to update a couple features in the OpenApiGenerator tool. As such I needed to use it's source code so I exported it to jar to use it easier but the problem is that it itself has a jar inside it that other classes use:
public class CodeGenMojo extends AbstractMojo
CodeGenMojo is in the jar I created from the source code and AbstractMojo is in a jar in the source code.
I'm still new to java and jars so I'm kind of lost here.

When I try to create an instance of CodeGenMojo I get:
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openapitools/codegen/plugin/CodeGenMojo
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openapitools.codegen.plugin.CodeGenMojo
And I wanted to make sure if it was even possible to use a jar within a jar or is it something else.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I'm _pretty_ sure no standard classloader looks for jars-within-jars. One thing you could do is to unzip the jar (a jar file is literally just a zip file with some filepath conventions) to get the internal zip file, and then manually create a class loader for that. Alternatively, you may be able to add the internal jar as a top-level dependency to your project (via maven, ant, etc — whatever you're using), and so not have to deal with the jar-within-a-jar issue at all. You'll have A(continains B) and B as two top-level jars in your classpath.

Comment: Which exactly features of the OpenAPI Generator do you need to change? If you need to change the code that it generates, this is done by [providing custom templates](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/templating) as as argument to the CLI/JAR.

Comment: I need to change it so that it creates the models into packages from the "tags" or "paths" of the provided json

Answer (score 0):

This sort of error implies that during runtime classes available when
first compiled are no longer available. Ensure that the application classpath includes your new jar files. Then rebuild your project. Also check if there are any other errors to see if this is caused by a static class failing to initialise. See [here](https://rollbar.com/blog/java-no-class-def-found-error) for more info

Comment: I'm using VS Code  and this is what I have in my settings.json
{
  "java.project.sourcePaths": ["src"],
  "java.project.outputPath": "bin",
  "java.project.referencedLibraries": [
    "lib/**/*.jar"
  ]
}
out of desperation I even added the jar that has AbstractMojo(maven-plugin-api-3.9.4.jar) as well in my main project and it still doesn't work. 
The classes are visible to the editor but not when executed.

Comment: So I think settings.json is only used by vscode hence visible to the editor but the project can’t actually see it. Are you using something like maven or gradle to build your project?

Comment: No i'm not using maven or gradle it's just a simple javafx project that i'm using to invoke the jar through an interface